# New bug after updating support library to 27.1.0

Tags: android, android-support-library

I was using support library version `25.3.1` for a long time, but since I wanted to support newer device too, I decided to update support library to the latest version.

But after updating to `27.1.0`, I have encountered an strange problem with `Snackbar`. I don't know if this problem is there for every other control too or not, but this is a super irritating(and obvious) one for `Snackbar`.

Now what is the problem? It is simple: If you update UI a lot, showing `Snackbar` is not done correctly and it is positioned incorrectly. Creating this situation is simple. Just create a new Basic Activity and change `onCreate` as follows:

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test_text);
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tv.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tv.setText(mVal.toString());
                    mVal++;
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 300);
}
```

This code simply updates a `TextView` every 300ms. Now if you press FAB, you see `Snackbar` will be positioned incorrectly. It will not be positioned exactly at bottom of screen, normally a little higher. You may need to test few times to see this problem, but normally you see it in first time. **NOTICE:** I didn't see this problem in emulator, but I saw it in real a device. For example it is shown on my Galaxy S5 and few other devices. It seems hardware requirement for these newer support library is increased significantly, or there is a bug in showing `Snackbar`.

Any idea why this happens? and what I should do about it?

Best Regards

Comment: Did you tried downgrading as i'm also facing a problem.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345777/auto-creating-new-intent-while-updating-setting-value-in-firebase-database)

Comment: I suggest to create an issue in _Issue Tracker_ for support library: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=190923&template=841312

Answer (score 0):

change view used by `Snackbar` to your `CoordinatorLayout`

```
rootLayout = findViewById(...);
Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
```

Comment: obviously root is `CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: sorry my mistake. what i mean is change view in snackbar to root layout

Comment: I have tested that too. Even if `Snackbar`'s root layout is exactly `CoordinatorLayout`, the same thing happens.